# zipping a folder and its sub folder

Tags: bash, directory, zip

Is there any way I can zip a folder and also zip one of the subfolder in a single line bash command?

```
Changes/
   folder1/
   folder2/
   folder3/
```

I want to zip `Changes` (parent folder) and `folder3` (sub-folder)

Note: I don't want to create zip folder extra (no duplication) i.e.
after zip I don't want to see this:

```
Changes.zip 
  Changes/   (Duplicate folder)
    Folder1/
    Folder2/
    Folder3.zip
     Folder3/ (Duplicate folder)
```

**Expected Output**

```
Changes.zip
  Folder1/
  Folder2/
  Folder3.zip
```

Code I've run

```
cd Changes/; zip -r ../Changes.zip * ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
cd Changes/ && zip -r Folder3.zip Folder3/* && rm -r Folder3/ && cd .. && zip Changes.zip Changes/* && rm -r Changes/
```

It's not elegant, but should work.

I've used `&&` instead of `;` so that it won't proceed to the second command unless the first completes successfully, and added the wildcard `*` to the end of each path to get the contents of the directory and not the directory itself ("no duplication", as you put it). Then we use `rm -r` to recursively remove the directory which has been zipped.

Comment: thanks for the reply but unfortunately nope didnt work.

Comment: @X00145570 - Can you explain how it didn't work please? Did you get any error messages? Can you show the results from when you tried it?

Comment: when i tried it . it created two folders (Changes). 1 is zipped and other one is normal. When i opened normal changed folder . There was another 2 folder (Folder 3) one is zipped and one normal . in that zip (folder 3) there was Changes folder and inside the changes folder files were located

Comment: Basically it duplicated the files without removing it

Comment: @X00145570 - I've updated my answer based on your feedback. See if the updated command works for you. It's not very elegant, and if you're doing something like this on a regular basis, or changing the names/locations of the directories, then you might want to consider a script instead of a 'one-liner'.